# Have similar theories like knot theory been developed in higher dimensions?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question, knot-theory

Well, my question is kind of basic but I hope it would be taken seriously by the community. Also, I'm very new to this topic and I want to study knot theory in future. Knot theory is the study of embedding $S^{1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Right?

So, it seems reasonable to consider embedding $S^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ for appropriate $(n,m) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. Are there any well-developed theories for these embeddings? If yes, is there a name for these theories? Are there any references to learn about them?

Also, I would be happy to know about some self-contained and good references to learn about knot theory and these higher order theories.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6053.pdf

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you. Do you happen to know a self-contained reference book for basic knot theory? I mean something that discusses knot invariants and stuff like that in detail? The arxiv article you sent is amazing, but it discusses knot theory in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in $4$ pages only.

Comment: Rolfsen "Knots and Links" is a standard reference.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you. I would appreciate it if you take the time to write an answer that the question doesn't remain in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: I like best the knot book by Adams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference to higher-dimensional knot theory:

E. Ogasa, [Introduction to higher-dimensional knots](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6053.pdf).

For classical knot theory, I like the book

D. Rolfsen, "Knots and Links".

It is a bit dated (written by 1970s) but very readable.